# shortcut of multi-conditions with and in AL and Business Central?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-al, businesscentral, msdyn365bc

Suppose we've procedure *`is_even`* return if the number given is even or not!
that's a good code:

```py
if is_even(22) = true or test(1) = true  or test(2)  = true then
    //...
```

And even that's a better:

```py
if true in [ is_even(22), is_even(1), is_even(2) ] then
    //..
```

But what if I would do that but with logic(*`and`* not *`or`*) like that

```py
if is_even(22) = true and test(1) = true  and test(2)  = true then
    //...
```

*Better code would be?*

I've tried to do that, So I think of do that with a function like in `python all`:

```py
local procedure all(array_bools : ARRAY [3] OF Boolean): Boolean
var
    bool: Boolean;
    i: Integer;
begin
    REPEAT
        bool := array_bools[i];
        if bool = false then 
            exit(false);
        i := i + 1;
    UNTIL i <> ARRAYLEN(array_bools);
    exit(false);
end;
```

and it is not working as I expect

```
if all([is_even(22), is_even(1), is_even(2)]) = true then
```

Comment: that seems overcomplicated. why not just `if not array_bools[i] then exit(false);`? also `<> ARRAYLEN(array_bools)` is doomed from the start. you want `> ARRAYLEN(array_bools)` because when `i = 0` (start of array) its automatically `<> ARRAYLEN(array_bools)`

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep it simple and readable. I think your code is hard to read because you combine all these checks in to one. Instead i would write something like this:

```
local procedure CheckMyConditions(): Boolean
begin
    if is_even(22) then
        exit(true);
    if test(1) then
        exit(true);
    if test(2) then
        exit(true);
    exit(false);
end;
```

Also this would perform better, because AL does not support lazy evaluation. This means every statement between "if" and "then" will be evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

The best for this cae ist here:
if is_even(22) or test(1) or test(2) then